# Example for complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

In my question I use the following notations:

$r,R\in\mathbb{R};$ $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C};$

$A'\left(\alpha,R\right)\dot{=}\left\{ z:z\in\mathbb{C},\left|z-\alpha\right|\leq R\right\};$

$A\left(\alpha,R\right)\dot{=}\left\{ z:z\in\mathbb{C},\left|z-\alpha\right|<R\right\};$

$C\left(\alpha,R\right)\dot{=}\left\{ z:z\in\mathbb{C},\left|z-\alpha\right|=R\right\}$.

I found the following theorem: Let $f$ be an analytic function on a simply connected domain $D$ and $A'\left(\alpha,R\right)\setminus\left\{ \beta\right\} \subset D$, where $\beta\in A\left(\alpha,R\right)$. If $0<r<R-\left|\beta-\alpha\right|$, then

$$\int_{C\left(\alpha,R\right)}f\left(z\right)dz=\int_{C\left(\beta,r\right)}f\left(z\right)dz.$$

Can you give me an example, where the two sides of the equation above is not zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by @JoséCarlosSantos this is not possible since the function is assumed to be analytic throughout the domain $D$ and by the Cauchy Goursat theorem integration along any closed path will be zero.  The situation is more interesting when the function has a point on non-analyticity within the domain such as a pole.  Then, if you assume such a point is contained within the interior of both curves (the point has winding number equal to say 1 with respect to both curves if you like) then the statement still holds and both integrals may not be zero.  This is an example of a deformation of contour which is a wonderfully useful technique used throughout complex analysis.

Comment: So if we don't claim $f$ is analytic on the whole $D$, then the statement is more interesting. Right?

Comment: More precisely: it would be a more interesting statement if the theorem would claim $\beta\notin D$....do I get it right?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just thinking out loud...but promise this will be my last comment for a while under this question...I think the best would be to state nothing about $D$...

Comment: Well, if $D$ is not simply connected then you need to talk about homotopy of the contours.  Integration along curves in a domain only depends on the homotopy class of the curve.   So if the two curves are not homotopic (can one curve be continuously deformed into the other without leaving the domain) then the equality does not hold.

Comment: But where do I go wrong in the following example then? What do I miss from the statement? $\alpha=1, R=3$, $\beta=0$, $r=\frac{1}{8}$, $D=\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{ 0\right\}$  and $f\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{z}$. In this case $\frac{1}{z}\in\mathcal{A}\left(D\right)$, $A'\setminus\left\{ \beta\right\} \subset D$, $\beta\in A\left(\alpha,R\right)$ and $0<r<R-\left|\beta-\alpha\right|$, however $\int_{C\left(1,3\right)}\frac{1}{z}dz=0\neq2\pi i=\int_{C\left(0,\frac{1}{8}\right)}\frac{1}{z}dz$. (Sorry for the lot of questions.)

Comment: In your example they are actually equal.  Both curves encircle the origin, then you can use the residue theorem or Cauchy integral formula to see they are equal.  Is this clear?

Comment: My comment was referring to a situation such as: your example but let $R=\frac{1}{2}$.  Then one integral will be zero and the other $2\pi i$.  The domain $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ is not simply connected and the curves $C(1,\frac{1}{2})$ and $C(0,\frac{1}{8})$ cannot be continuously deformed into one another without crossing the origin; they are not homotopic.

Comment: Yes, it is understandable, thank you. I think I see now where I went wrong in my example. I calculated $\int_{C\left(1,3\right)}\frac{1}{z}dz$ wrongly...

Comment: $\int_{C\left(1,3\right)}\frac{1}{z}dz=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{3e^{it}+1}i\cdot3e^{it}dt=\ldots$ and I think this is where I made the mistake $\ldots=\left[\ln\left(3e^{it}+1\right)\right]_{0}^{2\pi}=\ln4-\ln4=0$. But this is incorrect, because the formula $\int\frac{f'}{f}dt=\ln f+const$ can't be used here as in the real case, since $\ln z$ is not a primitive function for $\frac{1}{z}$. It is not even continuous at a given point on $C\left(1,3\right)$...

Comment: You need to account for the branch jump of the log when you go around a full loop that encircles zero; you must add $2\pi i$

Answer (score 1):

Since $D$ is simply connected, $f$ has an antiderivative, and therefore its integral along any loop is equal to $0$. So, no, nobody can do that.

Comment: But then why the theorem doesn't state explicitely that these integrals are zero? Ok...it doesn't lie, but we coud say more...why is it so special consequence of Cauchy's theorem, when it doesn't tell more or less than the Cauchy's theorem?

Comment: We could give an example if $D$ is not simply connected?

Comment: Sure: $D=\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$, $f(z)=z^{-1}$, $\alpha=0$, $r=1$, and $R=2$. Then both integral are equal to $2\pi i$.